# angular2 cannot find my component reference

Tags: javascript, html, intellij-idea, angular

I try to load my angular2 app and i get this error

[image]

although the files are in place.

[image]

How can i fix this?

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {PushComponent}  from '../../pages/push/push.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My 3rd Angular 2 App</h1> <push-comp></push-comp>',
    directives: [PushComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

and

app.module.js

```
import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpModule}     from '@angular/http';

import {AppComponent}  from './app.component';
import {PushComponent}  from '../../pages/push/push.component';

import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, PushComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: You have the file `push.component.ts`, but the browser is looking for `push.component`.

Comment: How are you loading you modules?

Comment: @ReidHorton so how should i change my code?

Comment: @ErnestoCampohermoso using intellij. added my module.ts

Comment: @ReidHorton is right, you should check the way your mapping is done in the client, it's most probably a default extension problem from your system.js config

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@NgModules` is not neccesary import the push component and the property `directives` in the `AppComponent`.

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My 3rd Angular 2 App</h1> <push-comp></push-comp>'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, as the navigator clearly says it. And your answer isn't good because he would have the same problem in his Module component.

Comment: It Is possible that PushComponent doesnt export the class. P.S. In the finish release of Angular must we remove directives property.